# Is it possible to destroy space stations in Elite?

Tags: elite

I've been playing the original Elite a lot via emulator and I was wondering if it's possible to destroy a space station (without cheating).  Just a couple of shots on a station will cause three Vipers to come after you, so it would definitely be a challenge.

Comment: I've never managed to destroy a space station, not for want of trying!  Indeed, all those Vipers get the better of you

Comment: After doing some research - although I have yet to try - if you have the cloaking device you can in theory blow it up as it has "strength" like an ordinary ship does, it's just higher than most ships.  One of the in-game missions is to destroy a Thargoid space station, it's essentially a regular space station but using the model of a Thargoid ship, so in that respect yes you can :-)

Comment: When I was younger I would load my Elite save files into a hex editor and change bytes randomly to see what they did. Once I ended up with infinite missiles (as long as I didn't buy any more) and I'm pretty sure I destroyed a space station by spamming missiles at it. I was disappointed to see the destruction animation was the same as destroying a ship: three or four triangles spinning for a second and then disappearing. (This was the PC version of Elite, played on an Amstrad 1512, when I was about 8 years old. I've since read that all space stations are undestroyable except the special one)

Comment: First find out if it at all can be destroyed: Memory train for infinite health and keep shooting the thing (or automate). While you wait, brew some tea.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can shut down a station by 'UA bombing' it, which means selling a lot of unknown artifacts to it (not literally bombing) which will shut down it's systems for awhile, but as far as I know the probes don't do anything to stations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can shut down the space station for a while. Use "UA bombing" method.

Comment: Could you detail what this entails? Note that the question is about the original 1984 game 'elite' and not the new 'elite dangerous'. Searches for 'UA bombing' only turn up results for the newer game, so I'm curious as to how it would apply here.